# SonarQube database using too much space (60+ GB)

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I'm currently scanning 70 projects with a total of about 2 million lines of code. All has been going well until a few weeks ago I was notified that a few projects failed because we ran out of hard drive space on the SonarQube server. I was sure we had more than enough space according to the HW/SW requirements. I read that restarting the Sonarqube server service does clear up temp files, but after doing that several times, something is still eating up more space. The culprit is coming from SQL server:

`...\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\sonarqube_log.ldf`

The size of this file is currently at 66.8 GB. Does anyone know if I can just truncate the stuff in there, know of any best practices for reducing this file size, and keeping the size down during future scans?

Comment: What [recovery model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275(v=sql.110).aspx) are you using?  If it's Full or Bulk Logged, how often are you backing up your transaction logs?

Comment: It's using "Simple", I don't think any backups are being taken either.

Comment: Simple recovery doesn't need transaction log backups.  On Full or Bulk Logged, the logs only flush when backed up but Simple is supposed to flush itself periodically.  What does `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)` say is the log space used percentage?  I'm guessing it's either very high (95%+) or very low (< 5%).  If it's very high, what is the output of `select name, log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases` for the SonarQube database?

Comment: DBCC SQLPERF(logspace);
     returned 94.48%

select name, log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases;
     returned log_reuse_wait = 2, log_reuse_wait_desc = LOG_BACKUP

Comment: Oops, I looked at the wrong database when looking at the recovery model, SonarQube's is set to 'Full'. *doh* The above queries are correct though.

Answer (score 2):

OK, if your database recovery is set to Full and you're not backing up the transaction logs, that's the problem.

If you want help understanding the differences between recovery models, then [start here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366344(v=sql.105).aspx).  The short version is that Full recovery allows point-in-time (aka, point-of-failure) recovery, meaning you can restore the DB to the exact moment before the problem occurred.  The drawback of Full recovery is that you *must* backup your transaction logs or this exact issue happens: the logs grow endlessly.  Simple recovery eliminates the need for transaction log backups (indeed, I don't think you can do a transaction log backup on a Simple database) but limits you to restoring the DB to what it was when you last ran a database backup.  Note that simple recovery still uses transaction logs!  The system just periodically flushes them.

So, you will need to do one of two things: Use Full recovery and backup your transaction logs periodically (I've seen systems that do it every hour or even every 15 minutes for high traffic systems), or switch to Simple recovery.  Those are your only real options.

Whichever one you do, switching to Simple or backing up the logs will flush the transaction logs.  You can verify that with `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)`.  However, you'll notice that `sonarqube_log.ldf` *will not change size at all*.  It will still be 66.8 GB.  This is *by design*.  In a properly managed system, the transaction logs will reach the size that they need to operate, and then the backups and simple flushes will keep the size constant.  The log file will be the proper size to run the system, so it will never need to grow (which is expensive) and will never run out of space (which would cause all transactions to fail).

"So, how do I get my disk space back?" you ask.  "I've fixed the problem so the log file is going to be 95% wasted space now."

What you'll need to do is shrink the log file.  This is something that you will often see written that you should never do.  And, I agree, in a properly managed system, you should never need to do this.  However, your system was not running properly.  The log files were on runaway.  In general, though, you shouldn't ever need to do this.

First, take a full database backup.  I repeat:  Take a full backup of your database.  This shouldn't cause any problems, but you don't want to be doing stuff like this without a fresh backup.

Next, you'll need to find the file id for the log file for the database in question.  You can do that like this:

```
select d.name, mf.file_id
from sys.databases d
join sys.master_files mf
    on d.database_id = mf.database_id
where mf.type = 1
    and d.name = 'SonarQube'
```

The `mf.type = 1` returns only transaction log files.  Use the name of your database if it's not `SonarQube`.

```
--Switch to the SonarQube database.  If you're not in the right context, you'll shrink the wrong file.
use [SonarQube]; 

--Do a checkpoint if you're on Simple recovery
checkpoint; 

--Do a log backup if you're on Full recovery
backup log ....

--Shrink logfile to 1 GB.  Replace @file_id with the id you got above.
dbcc shrinkfile ( @file_id, 1024 );
```

The size there is the size in MB.  You'll have to make a guess based on how large your DB is and how many changes you make to your system.  Something between 50% the size of the DB and 100% the size of the DB is pretty safe for most systems.  In any case, I would not shrink the logs further than 1 GB.  You'll need to monitor the log space and whether or not the log continues to grow.  The [Disk Usage report](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/01/sql-server-ssms-disk-usage-report/) in SSMS is a good way to do that.

The first time you run this, you may not see much gain in disk space at all.  It might go to 66.0 GB or 62 GB.  The reason for that is because the current tail of the log file is still at the end of the transaction log file.  What you should do is, if the system is under activity, wait a few hours and then run the above again.  That will give the system time to cycle the log back to the beginning of the log file, and you'll be able to shrink it down.  [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178037(v=sql.105).aspx) is a good article covering more about how shrinking the log file actually works, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks! I had switched it over to Simple last night and was able to free up the space using the instructions on the same site you gave me!